# Para que sirve el &gt y el &lt en un native query?

Tags: java, oracle, spring, sql

Tengo el siguiente native query pero no se que significa o para que sirve esto
&gt , &lt

```html
<query>
SELECT ID, ID_BASE, NOMBRE, RFC, NOMBRE_CLAVE, FEC_REGISTRO, FECH_PRINCIPAL
FROM FACTURA F
WHERE F.ID_BASE=?1
AND F.FEC_REGISTRO &gt;=TO_DATE(?2, 'DD/MM/YYYY hh24:mi:ss')
AND F.FEC_REGISTRO &lt;=TO_DATE(?3, 'DD/MM/YYYY hh24:mi:ss')
</query>
```

alguien podría decirme por que se ocupa?
o que significa en este query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`&gt;` es `>` (greater than) mayor que

`&lt;` es `<` (less than) menor que

```
AND F.FEC_REGISTRO &gt;=TO_DATE(?2, 'DD/MM/YYYY hh24:mi:ss')
```

se traduce a

```
AND F.FEC_REGISTRO >=TO_DATE(?2, 'DD/MM/YYYY hh24:mi:ss')
```

osea mayor o igual a ...

lo mismo para el `&lt;`

están codificados de esa manera pues deben estar dentro de un xml /xhtml y si pones el `<` ó el `>` directamente te rompe el esquema.

otra forma sería ponerlo asi

```
<query>
<![CDATA[

SELECT ID, ID_BASE, NOMBRE, RFC, NOMBRE_CLAVE, FEC_REGISTRO, FECH_PRINCIPAL
FROM FACTURA F
WHERE F.ID_BASE=?1
AND F.FEC_REGISTRO >=TO_DATE(?2, 'DD/MM/YYYY hh24:mi:ss')
AND F.FEC_REGISTRO <=TO_DATE(?3, 'DD/MM/YYYY hh24:mi:ss')

]]>
</query>
```

Comment: Gracias, me ayudo bastante!